# Visual Studio CPU Profiler / No Data

Tags: visual-studio

Today my CPU Usage Performance profiler in Visual Studio stopped working.  I start it, it seems like it's working, you can see the graph of the CPU going up and down but when it finishes I get no data with the message:

"There is no data in the current set of filters."

I have tried every combination of categories and filters with no luck.  I restarted Visual Studio, I rebooted the workstation, I tried against a new hello world project.  Other performance tools seem to work (e.g. the .NET Object Allocation Tracking tool works).  To (try) to rule out that it was something specific in my project I was able to successfully run it on a 2nd workstation against the same set of code.  I have also run VS without extensions and also in regular mode after disabling everything I've added in (like ReSharper).

*Edit:* Additionally I just found this in the Windows Event Viewer.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The method or operation is not implemented., System.Object get_Value()
   at EnvDTE.Property.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.ProjectTarget.LoadBinaryProject(IVsHierarchy hier)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.ProjectTarget.LoadProjInfo()
```

This also just popped up in the Event Viewer under "Windows Error Reporting" that referenced a Watson VSTelem.Out error:

```
Fault bucket 125730739576, type 5
Event Name: PerfWatsonVS12Data
Response: Not available
```

Another oddity is, I just ran a profile session for maybe 20 seconds, however when it's done VS says "Diagnostic session: 127:47 minutes" which would be the about the time I first time I tried it this morning if it never stopped.  I did a repair of Visual Studio from the installer and the profile worked for 1 session after, the 2nd session then reverted to the aforementioned behavior again.

I'm currently using:

- Visual Studio <strike>16.8.5</strike> <strike>16.9.1</strike> <strike>16.9.2</strike> <strike>16.9.3</strike> <strike>16.9.4</strike> 16.11.2
- .NET Core SDK: 5.0.201
- Windows 10 Version 2004 Build 19041.867

Any thoughts on fixes?

[image]

*Edit:* According to the following link, it might be related to a Windows Update and a bug in my NVidia driver:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-data-in-cpu-usage-tool-windows-update-related/1384519

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft confirmed the problem, as soon as a solution or workaround is found - report it. Follow the forum https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/profiling-cpu-still-states-no-user-code-was-runnin/607535?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1373491